Meteor Up Mongo error when running `mup setup`
Getting a confusing error when running mup setup:
mup setup                                                                                                                                ─╯

Started TaskList: Setup Docker
[10.10.35.220] - Setup Docker
[10.10.35.220] - Setup Docker: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Setup Meteor
[10.10.35.220] - Setup Environment
[10.10.35.220] - Setup Environment: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Setup Mongo
[10.10.35.220] - Setup Environment
[10.10.35.220] - Setup Environment: SUCCESS
[10.10.35.220] - Copying Mongo Config
[10.10.35.220] - Copying Mongo Config: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Start Mongo
[10.10.35.220] - Start Mongo
[10.10.35.220] x Start Mongo: FAILED

          ------------------------------------STDERR------------------------------------
          cat: mongo-start-current.sh: No such file or directory
    zsh:18: = not found

          ------------------------------------STDOUT------------------------------------

          ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

What's confusing is that when I Google mongo-start-current.sh, it returns exactly zero results. I don't have that string anywhere in my codebase, I've reinstalled mup several times, tried different node versions, reinstalled docker, tried every setting I could think of in mup.js, still get stuck at this exact spot every time.
This is being run locally on a Debian 12 baremetal server.
Here's my mup.js settings file:
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: '10.10.35.220',
      username: '[username]',
      password: '[password]'
    }
  },

  app: {
    name: 'my-app-name',
    path: '../',

    servers: {
      one: {},
    },

    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },

    env: {
      ROOT_URL: 'https://[mydomain].com',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor',
    },

    docker: {
      image: 'zodern/meteor:root',
    },

    enableUploadProgressBar: true
  },

  mongo: {
    version: '4.4.12',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    }
  },

  proxy: {
    domains: '[mydomain].com,www.[mydomain].com',
    ssl: {
      forceSSL: true,
      letsEncryptEmail: '[my@email.com]'
    }
  }
};

I'm rebuilding a system which is critical to a highly visible event we have twice a year at work coming up next week after a server failure. I'd really appreciate any help.

Well, turns out I wasn't using bash...
I don't know if it's stated that mup won't work on any shell other than bash, if it is I missed it. That was a waste of several days.
